# OpenLayers increase or decrease extent by a percentage

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5, angular-openlayers, openlayers-6

I have a map that has features on it and when I zoom to those features the user has the ability to set a preference as to the zoom buffer.

I'm not sure if there is a built-in way of doing this in OL...I've looked at the documentation but couldn't see anything...not sure if I just missed it?

```
zoomToSelectedFeatures() {
view.extent = MapOverlay.getSource().getExtent();
map.getView().fit(view.extent, MapValues.map.getSize());
}
```

Wondering if there is a way to plug a number in for say 20% that would make the zoom 20% larger?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `fit` method has a `padding` option but that is not expressed as a percentage so you would need to calculate padding based on the map size.  The easier way might be to scale the extent by converting to a geometry as `fit` can take either an extent or a geometry

```
geom = ol.geom.Polygon.fromExtent(view.extent)
geom.scale(1.2);
map.getView().fit(geom, {size: MapValues.map.getSize()});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Mike...what does the "1.2" represent?

Comment: scale the geometry 1.2 times i.e 100% + 20%